# how to do storage networking in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, storage, kubernetes

assuming that i have a working kubernetes cluster installed
if i create a pod with a persistent volume claim requesting 1GB of storage and i bind it to a local directory or nfs server
will kubernetes monitor the amount of data in the volume and stop if from exceeding 1GB? if not how can i implement such quota management?
in short how can i limit the amount of persistent volume for a pod or deployment or namespace?

Comment: It's up to the storage to do this, not Kubernetes. Which storage are you using?

Comment: not decided yet but any storage i can setup myself will do. like freenas

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kubernetes does not actually set any limits on storage.
it just uses the values specified to bind persistent volumes and persistent volume claims to each other